# gettin error while adding new employee record in open ERP 7 web client error is : Mail delivery failed

Tags: python, ubuntu-12.04, odoo, erp, window.opener

I got these error while creating new employee in open ERP 7 web client.

Please rply ASAP for this problem

Mail delivery failed

Mail delivery failed via SMTP server 'imap.googlemail.com'.
SMTPSenderRefused: 530
5.5.1 Authentication Required.

Learn more [at
5.5.1](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257)

f47sm17280432eep.13 - gsmtp
xyz@gmail.com

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have problems sending mails from your server. Try installing OpenERP in a different server, importing the database and emailing from that server. You can also try installing a smtp server (such as sendmail) in your server, and try sending an e-mail. That should work.

In a nutshell, your smtp server is not configured properly in your openerp server